# facebook Graph API search

Tags: php, json, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

For My application I need to create a search button which searches for posts using the facebook graph api search option.I obtained an access token and  when I type the same url in address bar I am getting the output as json array but if I try the same inside php function I am not getting the output.I am getting empty output.

My code for the search button

```
<form action="search_query.php" method ="GET">
<b>Enter Search Term:</b> <input type="text" name="query" size="100">
<input type="submit" value="search">


</form>
```

My code for getting the  search string and  getting the output json array.

```
<?php
$a= $_GET['query'];
$access_token='My_access_token';
$json_object=@fopen('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.$a.'&type=post&access_token='. $access_token);

 $b='https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.$a.'&type=post&access_token='. $access_token;
// echo $b;
 $json_object=@file_get_contents($b);
echo $json_object;
```

If I echo $b and paste the same url I am getting the correct output ,but If I  try using php function I am not getting ,please help

Comment: can you remove the @ in front of file_get_contents, and see what error messages it returns?

Comment: It says   " failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /var/www/search_query.php on line 4"

Comment: your ```$json_object``` is tied to both fopen and file_get_contents. It seems to be having a problem connecting to the url you have used for the graph search. What kind of search query are you testing this with?

Comment: I tried by commenting "fopen" and only  using "file_get_contents" .Even then Its throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Public Post search has been deprecated since April 30th 2014 with Graph API v2.0.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> Public Post search is no longer available.

Comment: No its available ... I tried and have been using that.I am unable to see if I use a a function to through php. I f I directly type the url I am able to see all public posts with the search keyword .If it was no longer available I would not have been able to see either way.

Comment: This is only possible if you generated the Access Token with a Graph API v1.0 app. And, this will stop working on April 30th 2015.